# How to sort array keys by other array keys?

Tags: php, arrays

For example i have two arrays like:

```
$first_array = array(
    1 => 'a',
    2 => 'b',
    3 => 'c',
    4 => 'd',
    5 => 'e'
);

$second_array = array(
    1 => 'not important',
    4 => 'not important',
    3 => 'not important',
    5 => 'not important',
    2 => 'not important',
);
```

Is there any function that could arrange first array keys (with values) in sequence of second array keys? Or i just need to loop second array and recreate first by keys?

**Update:**
Result values should be arranged by seconds arrays keys sequence

```
$result = array(
    1 => 'a',
    2 => 'd',
    3 => 'c',
    4 => 'e',
    5 => 'b'
);
```

Comment: ? I don't get it? What is the expected output?

Comment: No, you have to use loop for that.

Comment: contrary to popular belief php doesn't have a function/method for everything.

Comment: what would be the function header?

Comment: @gwillie just don't want to reinvent the bicycle

Comment: can you please elaborate how you want to achieve $result?

Comment: @RishabhRaj Result values should be arranged by seconds arrays keys sequence

Comment: @Kirix, Do you wan't to preserve the keys in the second array ?

Comment: [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-keys.php), [array_multisort](http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-multisort.php)

Comment: @Kirix, Which is source array and destination? We dont have such function upto my PHP knowledge. But we can build a new function for this....

Answer (score 0):

same question is already posted

[Sort array by keys of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685031/sort-array-by-keys-of-another-array)

[Sort an Array by keys based on another Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/348410/sort-an-array-based-on-another-array)

Hope will help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this...

```
<?php
$first_array = array(
    1 => 'a',
    2 => 'b',
    3 => 'c',
    4 => 'd',
    5 => 'e'
);

$second_array = array(
    1 => 'not important',
    4 => 'not important',
    3 => 'not important',
    5 => 'not important',
    2 => 'not important',
);


foreach($first_array as $k=>$v)
{
$second_array[$k]=$v;
}

$result = array_values($second_array);
array_unshift($result, "dummy");
unset($result[0]);
print_r($result);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => a
    [2] => d
    [3] => c
    [4] => e
    [5] => b
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it by using single foreach() loop and array_flip(); and array_combine();

```
     $f = array(
    1 => 'a',
    2 => 'b',
    3 => 'c',
    4 => 'd',
    5 => 'e'
);
$s = array(
    1 => 'dummy',
    4 => 'dummy',
    3 => 'dummy',
    5 => 'dummy',
    2 => 'dummy',
);
$c=array();
$j=1;
foreach($s as $k=>$v){

$c[]=$f[$k];

}
$f=array_flip($f);
$c=array_combine($f,$c);

print_r($c);
```